# Is it possible to recover message from MD5 and Java?

Tags: java, hash, md5

I have the following code.

```java
String plaintext = "HelloWorld";
MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.reset();
m.update(plaintext.getBytes());
byte[] digest = m.digest();
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1,digest);
String hashtext = bigInt.toString(16); 

// Now we need to zero pad it if you actually want the full 32 chars.
while(hashtext.length() < 32 ){
    hashtext = "0"+hashtext;            
}
```

Now I want to convert it back to the original string. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you heard of java.security package ?

Comment: Why is this tagged "md5"? Do you have a question about MD5? That's not an encryption algorithm, but a hash algorithm.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but note that `md5` (the tag you used) is not an encryption/decryption algorithm, but a one way hash algorithm

Comment: @PermGenError Bro dont downvote it. It is somewhat urgent.

Comment: @PrasadPofali I am not sure if that comment will positively influence the downvotes :)

Comment: @PrasadPofali Thing you have to understand is, MD5 is a One way hash. you are not supposed to reverse hash it.If you want to get the original plain text use some encryption/decrypition technique.

Answer (score 17):

> I have tried this. Now I want to convert it back to Original string.

This is not possible with MD5. It is a one-way [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

In order to be able to encrypt and decrypt, you need to use an encryption/decryption algorithm like AES.

See [Java™ Cryptography Architecture (JCA) Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) for more information.