# Decrypt a password of SecureSHA1 Hashing in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, hash

I have encrypted my password(Password1234$) using `SecureSHA1`and got the following

**Output**: `SHA1 hash for Password1234$ is 12a00057ae853a05601d5fafb7bc8141c37eaabe.`

I want to write a Decryption Method for the same so that if i pass my encrypted string `12a00057ae853a05601d5fafb7bc8141c37eaabe.` i need to get my password `Password1234$`

Below is my code which i used to Encrypt the Password.

**SecureSHA1.java**

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class SecureSHA1 {
    private static String convertToHex(byte[] data) { 
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
            int two_halfs = 0;
            do { 
                if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9)) 
                    buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
                else 
                    buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
                halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
            } while(two_halfs++ < 1);
        } 
        return buf.toString();
    }


    public static String getSHA1(String text) 
                throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException  { 
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] sha1hash = new byte[40];
        md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
        sha1hash = md.digest();
        return convertToHex(sha1hash);
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            String s = "Password1234$";
            String sha1S = getSHA1(s);
            System.out.print("SHA1 hash for "+ s+ " is "+ sha1S);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A one way hash function is not encryption, and SHA1 is a one way hash.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So, i cant get my password back once it was hashed with SHA1.

Comment: Exactly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521372/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-and-then-decrypt-a-string-using-md5-and-java (refers to MD5 but the concept is the same)

Answer (score 4):

There is a big difference between encryption and hashing. Encryption is designed so you encode and decode something using a key.

Hashing is specifically designed to be a one-way calculation. You can't get the input from the output, except by brute force.

SHA1 is a hashing algorithm.

Comment: Do we have any Brute Force Algorithm implemented.

Comment: A brute force approach would be to simple try to hash any possible input value until you create the same hash. If the input is short, like passwords, a list of pre-computed hashes helps. That's called a rainbow table. That is also a reason why you don't just hash password, but use a "salt". (google for "rainbow table" and "password salt" to learn more)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you cannot reverse an SHA1 hash!

See this post for further details:
[Is it possible to reverse a sha1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235079/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-sha1)